# Why binding/starting service is not working (lvl)

Tags: android, android-service, android-lvl

I am trying to modify the android lvl library and as part of this I included the code as part of my project source ( diff package) instead of using it as a library. However this code is failing

```
boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(
    new Intent(ILicensingService.class.getName()),
    this,  // ServiceConnection.
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

if (bindResult) {
  mPendingChecks.offer(validator);
} else {
  Log.e(TAG, "Could not bind to service.");
  validator.getCallback().stop("Could not bind to service.");   
}
```

It is saying:

```
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.myApp.com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService }: not found
```

Why is that? How can I fix it? It was working as library but when the code incorporated it does not

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You creating `Intent` i think incorrect. Try to replace yours with this:

```
new Intent(YourActivity.this, ILicensingService.class) //YourActivity is activity from its you want to start service.
```

**Note:** Don't forget add `Service` to `Manifest.xml`

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. Also this is google code from the licensing page. It used to work when used as a library  and there was not decleration of service. I am not sure  why it does not work when I import the source file? Maybe because it is different package?!